# Why does the car I'm currently driving spawn a lot more?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Whenever I steal and drive a particular car, that car suddenly starts to spawn a LOT more. To the point where it becomes ridiculous sometimes (e.g. Infernuses spawning non-stop) just because I'm driving one.

This happens to any car I find in the street, except special cars like police/ambulances/fire trucks.

Is this normal? I'm playing on an older PS3.

[image]

Comment: Related: [In GTA 4, does driving a particular vehicle make it appear more often?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229917/4797) and [What are the rules for spawning cars?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/226874/4797)

Comment: I've experienced a similar phenomenon in real life - whenever I buy a new car, I suddenly start noticing a lot more of the same make & model while I'm driving around :P

Comment: I remember the same happened in GTA4 and alaso GTA3

Comment: My personal conjecture has always been that the spawn rate increase was added to allow the player retain the same type of car they were driving, if for any reasons the player and the original car get separated, or the car gets trashed in the middle of a pursuit.

Comment: This was the case too with San Andreas. It was a bit frustrating, especially, when you were searching for a car (for a mission for instance), and when you eventually find it, it would then become available almost everywhere. :P However, this is done to save resources, since the number of car models the game loads consumes up memory.

Comment: I play GTA since Vice City (Playstation 2) and since then, the current car always "flooded" the map :D

Comment: I think this has been the case with all GTA games!

Comment: Can confirm it also happened in the original top down GTA!

Comment: @Steve-O I was hoping the real reason was a nod to this phenomena...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[According to this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634490-grand-theft-auto-v/67319499?page=1)

> The problem lies in the loading and unloading of vehicle models.
>   Apparently, each vehicle is so detailed that the system can only
>   afford to have a small number of models on tap. This "reserve" of
>   models changes based on your vehicle, location, and time. Vehicle
>   models are also loaded and unloaded each time the view is panned or
>   changed. If you ever notice looking down and empty street... Turn
>   around, turn back around, and now that street is full of cars within
>   seconds. That's just the games mechanics coupled with limitations of
>   the consoles. So when you steal a car you can pretty much always
>   expect to see your ride becoming very popular on the roadways.

Though it does refer this problem to console versions.
They could implement this workaround on PCs as well for low-grade PCs to run the game, but this is just speculation.

Answer (score 6):

From this [Gamefaq](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/933036-grand-theft-auto-iv/faqs/52803) (the last question at the last section of the page). It relates to GTA IV, but is fairly relevant still.

> I really wanted to drive  and when I first drove it,
>   suddenly  a whole bunch of them appeared! How is that possible?

The FAQ states that:

> Simple Answer: it is to speed up rendering speed. If every car you
>   passed by     was 100% different than the car behind it and infront of
>   it dont you think    it would slow the game down? they place alot of
>   variations of the same     vehicle your driving to prevent the game
>   from slowing down due to loading.

The FAQ continues with a more complex in-depth answer as well:

> Basically, the car models are too detailed for the RAGE 
>      engine to keep all of them cached and available to show up at any given 
>      time. So only a few cars are loaded into memory to spawn. But since the 
>      game has to have the car you're driving in cache, that puts it on a 
>      relatively short list of available cars to spawn, so all of a sudden 
>      everyone's got an Infernus.